# Is it possible to pass commands as variables to a --dialog script?

Tags: bash, scripting, variable, arguments, dialog

Currently I have the below dialog function that I am trying to make into a reusable yes/no prompt where I will be able to call it using YesNoPrompt followed by variables it will be needing.

The function looks like this:

```
function YesNoPrompt {
    dialog --begin 2 1 --no-shadow --title "$1" --hline "$2" \
        --backtitle "$3" --yes-label $4 --no-label $5 \
        --yesno "$6" 26 38 20>&1 > /dev/tty \
        || exit
    sudo reboot 
}
```

and is called like this:

```
YesNoPrompt "TITLE" "HLINE" "BACKGROUND TEXT" "YES" "NO" "MAIN MESSAGE"
```

Which works well enough but what I would also like to be able to pass options to it that would dictate what would happen if the user selects yes or no rather than the hardcoded exit and reboot that the function currently has.

Is there a way this can be done?

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The function below executes the command in parameter 7 if the `dialog` process exits with a non-zero exit status; otherwise -- if `dialog` exits successfully -- the function will execute the command in parameter 8.

```sh
function YesNoPrompt {
    if ! dialog --begin 2 1 --no-shadow --title "$1" --hline "$2" \
        --backtitle "$3" --yes-label "$4" --no-label "$5" \
        --yesno "$6" 26 38 20>&1 > /dev/tty
    then
      eval "$7"
    else
      eval "$8"
    fi
}
```

I reworked the logic away from `||` to a full-blown `if/then/else` statement; otherwise, your replacement for `exit` (if it doesn't `exit` or `return`) might allow the subsequent `sudo reboot` (or replacement) to *also* execute. Presumably you want only one or the other command to execute. I've also quoted all the parameters.

The `eval` is necessary if you want to pass more than one word in as the command (such as `sudo reboot`). Note that the `eval` causes the parameter to undergo another round of shell interpretation, so beware of things like wildcards or other expansions.